# Who is shown as being faster: X-Men Quicksilver or MCU Quicksilver?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, adaptation-comparison, quicksilver

*Based solely on on-screen feats*, who is the *Quickersilver*?

- Quicksilver from the Marvel Cinematic Universe
- Quicksilver from the live-action X-Men Universe?

I’m not looking for opinion-based answers, but answers based on things we actually see the characters doing in their respective movies.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvotes? It seems like a straightforward comparison between two incarnations of the same character. Its not like its a Flash/Quicksilver or Superman/Hulk comparison

Comment: Didn't DV, but I'd say because it's difficult to measure speed by sight. I could say in my opinion X was going faster than Y, but someone else might have felt the opposite. Also, just be cause one might have been *shown* to be faster/slower doesn't mean that they were reaching their full capabilities in that scene...

Comment: But I clearly stated "Based solely on on-screen feats", @cde points out the difference in reaction based on bullets which seems indicative of a faster speedster, but I'll wait to see if there is any more detail.

Comment: I’ve tried to make the question much more explicitly clear that it’s looking for evidence-based answers from the two movies in question. I’d also like to upvote it twice purely for using the word “Quickersilver”.

Answer (score 16):

Simply judging from an eyeballing of bullets shot from hand guns in each movie, the DOFP Quicksilver was shown to be quicker. He was able to move fast enough to calmly reposition multiple bullets in mid air, shown to be at a near stand still in relation to him. This is while doing other things.

On the other hand, AoU Quicksilver was taken by surprise by Hawkeye, and at his fastest point of view to the handgun bullet was noticeably slower. That is, the bullet was visibly slow, but not at a near stand still. He lost his footing underneath.

> Spoiler, that scenario foreshadowed something later in the movie.

Answer (score 4):

I think the Quicksilver in AoU was faster and stronger.
In DoFP QS was casually arranging bullets but remember these were from glass guns so the bullets would obviously be slower in 1973 while as QS in AoU was seeing a bullet as a slow moving object from a gun in 2015.
Also in AoU Quicksilver took a bullet that was Fired by Klaw and put it on his counter the second he fired it.

Comment: Muzzle velocity in the 1970s is comparable to that of the 2010s. Most firearms from the 60s and 70s have a MV of 2,000+, some even over 4,000+ (feet per second). MV of 4000+ was achieved in handguns and rifles as early as the 1930s.

Answer (score 2):

Both are like really quick but who is truly the quicker silver?

First, the MCU's Quicksilver. A minicarrier is around 29.6 metres, so using it as a reference the distance between Quicksilver and Hawkeye would be 302 metres. But you can't expect Quicksilver to run a 100% straight line, so I'd say he ran 350 metres. Quicksilver ran that distance in 1 second. So he would be subsonic. But wait a second. Again using as the minicarrier as a reference, the distance between Hawkeye and the Quinjet was 119 metres, which means he had only 0.14 seconds to save Hawkeye. 1 second isn't close. So in the scene where he caught Mjolnir, it took 2 full seconds for it to travel the length of one Aaron-Taylor Johnson, or 1.8 metres. Mjolnir travels at Mach 36, so Quicksilver would see things around 10 000 times slower. Then we can calculate that Quicksilver had to be running at Mach 10 274.

However, the X-men Quicksilver saved everyone from an exploding mansion. According to movoto.com, the mansion covers 76 654 square feet. Using the kitchen scene we know Quicksilver sees things 15 000 times slower. With the explosion being 150 seconds long to Quicksilver, the closest explosive would be the ONC which has a detonation velocity of 10 100 metres per second. So Quicksilver would have to be running over Mach 80 000. But we're still not there. In multiple scenes, he was a blur even time was slowed down. He ran out of the mansion in 0.3 seconds, and assuming the X-mansion is a square, that event happened in the centre and that the distance he ran outside is the same with the distance he ran in the inside then he would be Mach 1 in his own perception of time. With the average human sprinting speed being 7 metres per second, Quicksilver would have to be running at 5 times the speed of light.

X-men Quicksilver wins.